New Gnome Ubuntu won’t update to 46.1
The new regular Ubuntu 24.04 won't update to Gnome 46.1.
I have Gnome 46.
My Fedora 40 has Gnome 46.1.
Does Fedora have a different style to update?
I have done all the command lines and stuff.
Am I missing something?
Is it the PPA (Personal Package Archive)?

Is the answer below correct? If so please accept the answer by clicking the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Ubuntu updates vs Fedora updates
(More stable updates vs more frequent updates)
Ubuntu
Ubuntu aims for more stability. This is more true for LTS releases like 24.04. In general Ubuntu does not update any essential components of the OS, like Gnome unless there is a critical bug or a security vulnerability that needs to be fixing.
This results in a system that may look a bit old in 6 months, but is very stable.
See Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?
More on Ubuntu kernel updates for short and long term releases: Where can I find out when the next kernel version will be released for my distro version?
Fedora
Fedora is the initial testing ground for what goes in (or does not) into Red Hat. This means every new update gets thrown into Fedora. Even though Fedora has a six month release cycle like Ubuntu, more parts of the OS gets updated within that cycle, such as the kernel, or in this case Gnome, in Fedora as compared with Ubuntu.
Hope this helps

To upgrade by patching Ubuntu Noble Gnome Mutter 46.0 to 46.1-1, use the mutter package of "ppa:jbicha/arch2" repository.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jbicha/arch2
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mutter
mutter --version

ref) see the link at the bottom of launchpad mutter page. => https://launchpad.net/~jbicha/+archive/ubuntu/arch2see also debian experimental changelogs of Mutter

For Ubuntu Gnome Mutter v46.1-2 package, make a folder and download ".deb" files from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/46.1-2ubuntu1/+build/28374184. Then,
sudo apt install ./*.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./mutter-common_46.1-2ubuntu1_all.deb


For other Ubuntu Gnome 46.1 utilities like Nautilus 46.1 and etc, see also https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

